# How to move menu next to left of the search box?

Tags: customization, menus

I use Woocommerce plugin and StoreFront theme to build my demo website at http://52.74.97.64/wordpress/

I want to move the current menu to another place - on the left next to the search box on the top right corner.

How can I do that?

p.s. The `header.php` file can be viewed [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6194904/2015/%28wordpress%20stackexchange%29%20header.php) (be updated soon)

[image]

Comment: Post your code of `header.php and URL` of the site.

Comment: Try something by yourself first then make a fiddle.

Comment: @ManojKumar I have updated my OP to add your suggested information.

Comment: @ManojKumar Which header.php you want to see? The `themes/storefront/inc/structure/header.php` or the `include/theme-compat/header.php`

Comment: I have already answered Nam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple solution of

1. Setting the menu position to `Secondary navigation`, AND `Handheld`
2. Setting an empty menu for for position `Primary navigation`.

In my screenshot I haven't removed the primary navigation though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Though when unchecking the `Primary Menu`, the default menu will appear. Please go on ^^ - how can I just showing the `Secondary Menu` only?

Comment: I guess you have finished it? :)

Comment: Still missing the last step to complete an accepted answer @ManojKumar - turning off the default menu

Comment: But I don't see any default menu from my end. You have three locations, Primary, Secondary and Handheld. Set Secondary to your menu and leave the primary and handheld to 'Select a Menu`

Comment: @ManojKumarLeaving the Primary as 'Select menu' will show the default menu from nowhere. I have to create an empty menu and assign it to Primary.

Comment: By the way is handheld menu used for mobile version?

Comment: Yes they are used for mobile, tablet.

Comment: Thanks @ManojKumar. Please update your answer to include putting in the empty menu for `Primary` and set the current menu for `Secondary` and `Handheld`. I'll make it accepted for you ^^

Comment: Done @NamGVU Hope that helps!